# The reference to entity "c" must end with the ';' delimiter

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project and I need to add server details in `settings.xml` to gain access to a repo that needs authentication.

I have the following, where mypass includes this `&c%` substring.

```
<server>
    <id>myid-releases</id>
    <username>myusername</username>
    <password>mypass</password>
</server>
```

Comment: Replace the `&` in in you password with `&amp;`

Comment: @f1sh Thanks a lot! You add it as an anwser to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `&` is a special character in xml because it marks the start of a so-called entity.

If your xml parser (or the one that maven uses) tries to resolve entities, they need to be valid. Thus, you need to place the entity that resolves to `&` into your xml: `&amp;`

TL;DR:
Replace the `&` in in your password with `&amp;`